# can I deploy docker on google cloud VM instance without host network

Tags: docker, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I want to use following method to open jupyter with brower:

```
docker run  --runtime=nvidia --name tensorflow1 -it  -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

but it did't work.

while I can open website with following method:

```
docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx
```

my question is can I use docker without host network and how?

Comment: i suspect your nvidia-docker to cause the troubles. which error do you get for the first command?

Comment: no error, I agree with you, but I don't know how to solve nvidia-docker problem, reinstall?

Comment: how did you install it in the first place

Comment: first,I install docker according to (https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/), then I installed nvidia-docker according to (https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker). Maybe it is only needed one of them?